# PHPMailer strange behavior when sending email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Recently i changed my mail services from contabo server to hostinger, Im using the correct credentials and host from hostinger but when i try to send email receiving only on contabo and not on hostinger
One notice , My web services for that domain is on contabo , my mail services is on hostinger, im using cloudflare and i make few times purge cache with no luck

````
    $to_Email       = "info@xxx.gr"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Message from website '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Subject line for emails

    $host           = "smtp.hostinger.com"; // Your SMTP server. For example, smtp.mail.yahoo.com
    $username       = "info@xxx.gr"; //For example, your.email@yahoo.com
    $password       = "xxxxx"; // Your password
    $SMTPSecure     = "ssl"; // For example, ssl
    $port           = 465; // For example, 465
    ```
````

Comment: Have you checked your SFP record? You could use a service like mailtrap.io or mail-tester to check on your mails and why they won't arrive.

Comment: @halfpastfour.am I checked , my spf from mail-tester is : v=spf1 include:_spf.mail.hostinger.com ~all

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the domain name present.
However, as I understand sending is okay, but receiving isn't.
And that is related to DNS records. Ensure that enough time has passed since your MX records change (up to 48-72 hours).

Because in some locations your MX (Mail Exchange) records could be Hostinger's and in other areas - Contabo's. You can also use https://dnschecker.org/, insert your domain name, select MX from a dropdown list and click "Search". It will show your MX records in all locations.

Receiving always depends on MX records or in other words, these records tell where to deliver your email.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dnscheker seems to point on hostinger, so everything looks normal.

https://prnt.sc/z-3-0Xocmw7l